# unload not working in IE9 and FF4

Tags: internet-explorer-9, firefox4, window.onunload

```
var unloadOK = "false";//used as variable when data need to be send to the server
window.onbeforeunload = CheckBeforeUnload;
window.onunload = CheckUnload 

function CheckBeforeUnload(){
  document.getElementById("ContentPlayer").CheckUnload("");
  return "Are you sure you want to exit?"
}

function CheckUnload(){
  unloadOK = "true"; 
  pause(1000);

  alert("session saved");
}

function pause(millis) 
{
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;

  do { 
    curDate = new Date(); 
  } while(curDate-date < millis);
}
```

Above is the code: I am trying send data when user trying to close the browser.
Onunload method work in IE7 and IE8 but not in IE9 and FF4. 
 Application is built in Flex 3.0 sdk.

Can anyone suggest what is the issue with onunload is there solution to send data reliably when browser is closing and how onunload work consistently in all browser?

Answer (score 0):

> Above is the code: I am trying send
>   data when user trying to close the
>   browser. Onunload method work in IE7
>   and IE8 but not in IE9 and FF4.
>   Application is built in Flex 3.0 sdk.

Not sure how much it will matter, but try putting the function calls before you assign them as handlers.

```
function CheckBeforeUnload(){
  document.getElementById("ContentPlayer").CheckUnload("");
  return "Are you sure you want to exit?"
}
```

You probably want an `alert()` here instead of a `return`

> Can anyone suggest what is the issue
>   with onunload is there solution to
>   send data reliably when browser is
>   closing and how onunload work
>   consistently in all browser?

Unfortunately a user can simply close the tab your page is on and circumvent it. They could also use, say, Google Chrome's process monitor to kill the tab. Finally, they can force quit the application. It's bad to depend on this functionality as the end all solution.

Comment: Requirement: 
To show warning message when browser is closing.  
To send data only when browser is closing for sure.

onbeforeunload method return is used to show default warning. alert will work but not will work as a warning message with ok and cancel option.